# Writing a code to create an array and display the index number else display "Item not found"

Tags: c++, arrays

Write a code to create an array with the following elements: a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k. Test if the array contains a specific character provided by the user. If found display the index number else display " Item not found".

Comment: The problem description is unclear. Please add an example of input and desired output to the question.

Comment: Can you show the program you've already written, and explain how exactly your program doesn't work or doesn't produce the expected results? You have to show your work first; it must meet all requirements for a [mre]; and it must be a good-faith real attempt to implement your program and not a few token lines of code, before asking for help on stackoverflow.com. stackoverflow.com is a question and answer site *but we don't write code for other people*, here. For more information, see [ask] questions, take the [tour], and read the [help].

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like some sort of assignment to me...

The first step is to create an array. There is a c++ array type, but I'm assuming you're supposed to use the basic c array.

To do this you declare an array of whatever type you want it to contain and of the number of elements with the following syntax

```
type ArrayName[NUMBERofELEMENTS];
```

Then you fill it with a for-loop or with the following syntax during declaration

```
type ArrayName[NUMBERofELEMENTS]= {element1_OfType,element2_OfType....NumberofELEMENTS};
```

In your case the type can be char (since you're creating a list of 1 char each item) or a string.

So your main will contain something like this

```
char old_school_array[12]={ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k','\0'};
find_element('i',old_school_array);
```

Now let's do the find_element function.

Goal: take 1 letter and tell if it is in some array, so we need to pass 2 arguments to the function, the array and the element. They question says "If found display the index number else display " Item not found"." so obviously a display is just a cout the exercise **does not ask you to return**. Normally we write a function as follows:

```
returnType functionName(args1...){
// function body
}
```

in your case you don't need to return and we just explained the arguments we need so
`void find_element(char e, char arr[] )`

Now how to find the position of the element if it exists? For this we need to visit every single element of the array and check if this element == the search element. A nice way to visit each element is loops (while and for)

with a for you can the following:

```
for (int i=0; i<MAXSIZE;i++){
        if (arr[i]==e) {
            // do things
        } //end if
    }// end for
```

if you enter the if (the part with do things) you just need to output as asked, and since you found what you're looking for you can "stop" the function by returning immediately.
if the for loop finished (i.e we visited every element of the array) without entering the if condition, then the element does not exist. so print the "not found" sentence.

all together:

```
void find_element(char e, char arr[] ){
    for (int i=0; i<MAXSIZE;i++){
        if (arr[i]==e) {
            cout << "found at "<< i<<"-th position"<<endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    cout << "Could not find  "<< e<<" in array"<<endl;
}



int main()
{
    
    char old_school_array[12]={ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k','\0'};
    find_element('i',old_school_array);

    return 0;
}
```

P.S: If this is some sort of assignment please make sure to understand every step I explained or ask for clarifications in the comments on my answer. Normally such questions not showing any effort of trying to solve the problem on your own are not appreciated here but I'm being nice since I know most classes are now done online due to covid-19 and it's pretty hard to follow in such conditions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I promise I will understand every step you explained.